# XMPP_LOGGING_ENABLE=0 not disabling logging

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I use both [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) and also [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack) in other parts of my app.

I want to limit or rather **globally disable all logging made by XMPPFramework**.
I realised the I should set `XMPP_LOGGING_ENABLED` to `0`, so I tried:

- Putting `#define XMPP_LOGGING_ENABLED 0` in many places (.h and .m files), and none of them manage to stop the logging from happening!
- Setting `GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER` to `Yes` and `GCC_PREFIX_HEADER` with some `pch` file that defines `#define XMPP_LOGGING_ENABLED 0` with no luck.
- Since I have multiple targets, I tried to play with `GCC_INCREASE_PRECOMPILED_HEADER_SHARING` and also NO LUCK.
- Setting  a `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_NOT_USED_IN_PRECOMPS` entry  with `XMPP_LOGGING_ENABLED=0`.
- Even tried playing with `XMPP_LOG_LEVEL_OFF` in different places.
- Modifying `XMPP_LOGGING_ENABLED` in the `XMPPLogging.h` source is *not* an option as I'm using Cocoapods.

None of the above worked :(... Would appreciate some assistance here - how do I get rid of (default-ly very verbose) XMPPFramework logging?

Comment: BTW, opened an issue here: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/702.

Comment: One option is to use this fork: https://github.com/Josephwaelchli/XMPPFramework.
But keep in mind that it won't update when XMPPFramework does.